# How to detect the rails version from an installed ruby gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I want to modify an existing gem to compatible with new rails versions. My requirement is as follows

I have a gem which runs in both rails 2 and 3. But it has some stylesheet copy functions. So as you already know rails 2 has stylesheets in `public/stylesheets` folder, But in rails3 has assert pipe line.

So what I want to do it, I want to detect the rails version using by my gem installed rails application and according to the version I will handle the file copy.

**My question is How an installed ruby gem reads the current rails applications version ?**

Or **is there any other way to do it ?**

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took a look around in the latest stable source for Rails and found a `version.rb` file which indicated I could do this:

```
Rails::VERSION::STRING  #=> "3.2.6"
```

If you look at [Rails 2.3](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/2-3-stable/railties/lib/rails/version.rb), you’ll find that the same thing works there.